# PHP Get Echo ?! Android

Tags: php, android

Hey Guy´s i want to ask u, why my app is crashing... I dont know why
i tried out much more ways but i still cant fix it.
Here ist my Problem out of the LogCat:

```
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3063)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3534)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14263)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3058)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     ... 11 more
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1108)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:391)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:242)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:71)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     at com.me.bittwaldstream.MainActivity.sendLogin(MainActivity.java:163)
05-14 14:03:22.268: E/AndroidRuntime(4674):     ... 14 more
```

And here is my function which produce the Crash...

```
public void sendLogin(View v) {
        /*getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, new WaitFragment())
                    .commit();*/

        EditText username;
        EditText passwort;
        String result = "";
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
        passwort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPasswort);

        if(username.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte geben Sie einen Usernamen an", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(passwort.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bitte geben Sie ihr Passwort an", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://shop.kokakukidotai.cf/echotest.php");
            HttpURLConnection mUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            mUrlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(mUrlConnection.getInputStream());
            result = readStream(is);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        if(result == "allow")
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login erfolgreich", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because you are calling network call in Main(UI) thread. so you need to put your call inside asynctask

Answer (score 2):

> "Network operations can involve unpredictable delays. To prevent this
>   from causing a poor user experience, always perform network operations
>   on a separate thread from the UI."

you need to perform Networking Tasks in an AsyncTask and not on the MainThread.

Like this

```
private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";
      for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
          InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
  }

  public void onClick(View view) {
    DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.vogella.com" });

  }
```

Taken from http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_asynchtask

Also, make sure this is in your android manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`